# Using custom icons in title with JOptionPane.showInputDialog

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

I'm trying to use a custome icon in the title of the JOption pane rather then with the label. Is there a way that I can do that? I'm using the Icon class (as shown below) in `JOptionPane` but it keeps displaying the icon in the main display area rather than in the title. 
Here is the code:

```
Icon icon = new ImageIcon(ApplicationManager.getApplicationImage().getImage());
String jid = (String)JOptionPane.showInputDialog(ApplicationManager.getMainWindow(), 
                 Res.getString("label.enter.address"), 
                 Res.getString("title.start.chat"), 
                 JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, 
                 icon,                    
                 null, 
                 selectedUser);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Try this code..

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.net.URL;

class OptionPaneIcon {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JOptionPane jop = new JOptionPane(
            "Message",
            JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
            JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION
            );

        JDialog dialog = jop.createDialog("Dialog Title");

        Image image = ImageIO.read(new URL(
            "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/f1d58f7932b6ae8027c4e1d84f440ffe?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG"));
        dialog.setIconImage( image );
        dialog.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The JOptionPane takes its icon from the parent frame. So you can set the icon on a dummy JFrame, and pass that into the JOptionPane call:

```
    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new URL(
    "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/f1d58f7932b6ae8027c4e1d84f440ffe?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG"));
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setIconImage(image);
    JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame, "Enter Address", "Chat",
            JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, null, "");
```

Note, this will likely cause issues with the location of the shown dialog, as it will be placed relative to the dummy JFrame passed in.

Answer (score 1):

Haven't tried it, but you might get it to work with an internal frame, rather than using a dialog box. Try creating an instance of `JOptionPane` and call `getInternalFrame()`. JInternalFrame has a `setFrameIcon(Icon icon)` method.

Edit: On course the `JInteralFrame`'s parent must be a `JDesktopPane`, but apart from this it should work.

Comment: This would not work as I have some pre selected value that I need to populate the Input dialog box with and hence cant use the JOptionPane constructor but instead have to use showInputDialog method..

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

HI,

This would not work as I have some pre selected value that I need to populate the Input dialog box with and hence cant use the JOptionPane constructor but instead have to use showInputDialog method..

Hence, I believe I cannot use a custome icon when using showInputDialog(.,.,.,.,.,.,.)

Thanks.